# Unable to retrieve data from firebase databse in 2 activities

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, backend

Here's JSON:

```
{

  "users" : {
    "QTJ1xqpKP5TojSUnbvJkYl6XOWI2" : {
      "Collection" : {
        "-LrOoIXnTA5OgItNyq7x" : {
          "movie" : "x",
          "Name" : "xxxxxx",
          "id" : "-LrOoIXnTA5OgItNyq7x"
        },
        "-LrOp480npJrLLvuJPIE" : {
          "movie" : "xsss",
          "Name" : "yyy",
          "id" : "-LrOp480npJrLLvuJPIE"
        }
      },
      "contributionCounter" : 0,
      "id" : "-LrOoFF3paOUttLnriwU",
      "inventoryCounter" : 0,
      "password" : "123456",
      "reqCollection" : {
        "-LrP3gCtIM7UDhaDuA5U" : {
          "movie" : "y",
          "Name" : "xReq",
          "id" : "-LrP3gCtIM7UDhaDuA5U"
        }
      },
      "requestCounter" : 0,
      "username" : "x"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch child_1 data in MainActivity.java and child_2 data in RequesList.java. The problem is, after installing app, i'm able to retrieve child_2 data in required activity but it doesn't show data of child_1 in my main activity. Again, after relaunching the app, everytime it show me child_1 data in main activity (which is required) but it doesn't show child_2 data anymore.

Here's my MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter  firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebasedatabase;


private DatabaseReference myRef;

private RecyclerView rv;

public  void  add(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void reqSearch(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Requestt.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

private void firebaseCollectionSearch() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   Query searchQuery ;
   searchQuery=myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Collection").orderByChild("Name");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Collection> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Collection>()
                    .setQuery(searchQuery, Collection.class)
                    .build();
```

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(

```
            options
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CollectionViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Collection model) {

            holder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getRName());

            Log.i("request: ",model.getRName());

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RequestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.collection_list, parent, false);

            return new CollectionViewHolder(view);


        }


    };

    rv.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mFirebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebasedatabase.getReference("users");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.CollectionListRecyclerView);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    firebaseCollectionSearch();



    ImageButton img = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.profile);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



   // BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomnavigation);
    //navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);



}

public static class CollectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public CollectionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(String name, String rName)
    {
        TextView s_name = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.SNameSingle);
        TextView r_name = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.RNameSingle);


        s_name.setText(name);
        r_name.setText(rName);


    }




}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();


    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }




}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

Here's my RequestList.java

```
public class RequestList extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebasedatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
FirebaseUser user;

private RecyclerView rv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_list);

    mFirebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebasedatabase.getReference("users");
    myRef.keepSynced(true);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reqListRecyclerView);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    firebaseRequestSearch();


}

private void firebaseRequestSearch() {


    Query searchQuery =myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("reqCollection");


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Requests> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Requests>()
                    .setQuery(searchQuery, Requests.class)
                    .build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Requests,RequestListViewHolder>(

            options
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RequestList.RequestListViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Requests model) {

            holder.setDetails(model.getName(),model.getRName());

            Log.i("req: ",model.getRName());


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(RequestList.this, model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                }
            });

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RequestList.RequestListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.req_list_layout, parent, false);

            return new RequestList.RequestListViewHolder(view);


        }


    };

    rv.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class RequestListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public RequestListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(String name, String rName)
    {
        TextView s_name = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.reqNameSingle);
        TextView r_name = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.reqRNameSingle);


        s_name.setText(name);
        r_name.setText(rName);

    }



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
   firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();


    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: JSON added. Sorry i didn't add it before.

Answer (score 0):

you did not initialise `myRef`in your `MainActivity` add these line before `searchQuery` initialization

```
mFirebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = mFirebasedatabase.getReference("users");
Query searchQuery;
searchQuery=myRef.child(user.getUid()).child("Collection").orderByChild("Name");
```

Hopefully it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it doesn't solved my problem.